# Exposing azure functions from subprojects

Tags: asp.net, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have several projects that define azure functions (entry points annotated with `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.FunctionNameAttribute`), and I want to merge them into one function app.

When I create a project that references all of them (there are no calls between the assemblies though; just the project declares references) and publish it, it collects all of the assemblies in it's `bin` directory and resolves dependencies correctly. However, it does not generate the `function.json` files needed to enable those entry points.

Is there a way to persuade the handler of that attribute to process it for the referenced assemblies as well?

---

- Related use case: [Expose Azure Functions in Nuget Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015745/) (without solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hacky solution that seems to be working involves:

- In the solution I created a `dependencies` project, moved all the package references—except `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` into that project, and referenced it from all the function projects.

  - The `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` reference is magical as it triggers generation of the `function.json`. Fortunately nothing else depends on it, so it's easy to keep that dependency consistent between the projects.
  - This was the only way to make sure the versions of *indirect* dependencies are consistent without listing them everywhere.
- Then I publish the solution, which publishes all the projects, generating the `function.json` in all the ones that reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`.
- And last I merge all the published directories, checking files with the same name always have the same content.

  - That also means putting the same `host.json` in all the functions, which almost certainly makes sense.
- The other `.json` files that are generated in each project have to be merged, which makes it incredibly fragile.

The whole thing clearly goes against what Microsoft intended, which is having one project per functionapp.